# Voltage Subtractor this circuit:

Tags: voltage, amplifier, differential

Is this a voltage subtractor switching the position of Q1 with Rc1 and Q2 with Rc2 ?Also if we want current to flow from the + sign to the - sign how many times bigger resistor than Rc2 and Rc1 do we need?

[image]

Comment: it is unclear what you are actually trying to ask .. if you want current to flow from + to -, then take a piece of wire ... connect one end to  +Vcc and connect the other end to -Vee

Comment: Let V1 >V2. If I connect it with wire the voltage drop at Rc2 will be increased (because there is extra current(in parallel) flowing from -Vee to Q1. Therefore it will stop working as a differential amplifier.If I put a huge resistor between the + and - the current will be very small and the voltage drop at Rc2 will remain approximately the same.

Comment: there is no V1 and no V2 in the diagram